# CXF: How to set global receive timeout with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, networking, cxf

I'm trying to set client's receive (read) timeout on CXF for all SOAP outbound communications. And we use Spring.
I put

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.*">
    <http-conf:client
        ReceiveTimeout="300000"
        />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

in beans configuration in attempt to set new timeout for 5 min instead of default one minute, but nothing happens, I still see only 1 minute timeout. Also, I'd like to do it in configuration, not in the code like in some examples I found on the web.

Did I miss something?

Should configuration somehow different?

How do I set new timeout across all SOAP outbound communications with CXF?